# Branding the list Search Box

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, css, branding

I'm building a site collection in SharePoint OnI want to apply some custom css rules to the List Search Box that you can enable in the List Web Part edit menu.

I've tried using the element inspector in firebug but I can't find the DIV class that I need to reference in the  tag.

Can anyone with a little more branding experience of SP2013 tell me which class I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outter div of the list search box is `ms-InlineSearch-DivBaseline`
The inner div is `ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Baseline ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Empty`